# fgets falls through without taking input

Tags: c, fgets

whenever I call this function it fails to give the use a chance to enter the string. Not sure why pretty sure my syntax is spot on. think I has something to do with the newline but I don't know how to get rid of it

```
 void serchName(dealers_t *ptr, int numDealers)
{
    char dealerName[NAME_LEN];
    int index;

    printf("please enter the dealer's name:");
    fgets(dealerName, sizeof(dealerName), stdin);
    system("PAUSE");

    for (index = 0; index < numDealers; index++, ptr++)
    {
        if (strcmp(dealerName, ptr->name) == 0)
        {
            printf("MATCH FOUND:%s\n%s\n%s\n%i\n%s\n", ptr->name,ptr->city,ptr->state,ptr->zip,ptr->phone);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have something in stdin from before the call. Make sure you don't.

Comment: fflush(stdin); perhaps?

Comment: @Jim Only if you want undefined behaviour.

Comment: scanf("%c%*c", &ch);  /* to avoid flushing stdin */

Comment: I am curious, How is 'NAME_LEN' defined?

Comment: This post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876091/c-flushing-stdin, might help.

Comment: Fgets also reads the terminal '\n' into the buffer, so the strcmp() will fail (unless the ptr->name also has an '\n' at its end)

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have some `'\n'` left-over from previous I/O activity.

It is **best** to use `fgets()` and not mixed with  `scanf()` in the same program.

But since I can not see the other code, suggest the following to consume a left-over `'\n'`.

```
printf("please enter the dealer's name:");
int ch;
ch = fgetc(stdin);
if (ch != '\n') ungetc(ch, stdin);
if (fgets(dealerName, sizeof(dealerName), stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
```