# fflush() function not working with stdin

Tags: c, stdin, fflush

I'm sorry for this silly question. I have C program to prompt user to enter age and name and
then print the age and name to the screen. This is my exercise that I read from book.

This the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   int age;
   char name[20];

   puts("Enter your age:");
   scanf("%d",&age);

   fflush(stdin);

   puts("Enter your name:");
   scanf("%s",name);

   printf("Your age is %d\n",age);
   printf("Your name is %s\n",name);

   return 0;
}
```

When I enter extra characters to the first `scanf()` the program terminates and assign the extra characters to the next `scanf()`

And then I changed the code, and add function named `clear_buff()` and using the `fgets` function within the `clear_buff()` to read the remaining characters on stream.The code work as I expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 80

void clear_buff(void);

int main (void) {
  int age;
  char name[20];

  puts("Enter your age:");
  scanf("%d",&age);

  clear_buff();

  puts("Enter your name:");
  scanf("%s",name);

  printf("Your age is %d\n",age);
  printf("Your name is %s\n",name);

  return 0;
}

void clear_buff(void){
   char junk[20];
   fgets(junk,MAXLEN,stdin);
}
```

My question is why `fflush(stdin)` not working in this program?

The book says that `fflush` function clear any buffered data on the stream.And I know that 
`fflush()` function is the C standard function if working with I/O stream.

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: `fflush` is for clearing the output. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) for how to clear the input.

Comment: `fflush` on an input stream (such as `stdin`) has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fflush` is meant to work with output or update streams and using it with an input stream is undefined behavior, from cppreference C section for [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush):

> The behavior is undefined if the given stream is of the input type or if the given stream is of the update type, but the last I/O operation was not an output operation.

[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is behavior that the standard does not specify and it means that the result of your program is unpredictable, which could mean behavior that seems normal or a crash or other undesirable effects.

cppreference is consistent with the language in the draft C99 standard section `7.19.5.2` *The fflush function* which says:

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the
>   most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any
>   unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment
>   to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Although this is not really your question and it seems like you have figured out a work-around, the question [C, flushing stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3876091/1708801) covers some proper ways of flushing `stdin`.

Comment: can you explain to me what is exactly the means of `The behavior is undefined if the given stream is of the input type or if the given stream is of the update type, but the last I/O operation was not an output operation` I'm sorry I just start to learning C,I have try to understand that statement and still don't understand.

Comment: @harianja I added some more details on undefined behavior. If you were referring to the difference between input, output and update streams then that would opening a stream for reading, writing or both reading and writing. See [fopen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) for the different modes.