# Stack around the variable was corrupted

Tags: c, gets

I am having a problem with `gets`.

The purpose is to get input from the user until he hits the 'Enter'.

This is the code:

```
struct LinkedListNode* executeSection2()
{
    char inputArr [3] = {'\0'};
    struct LinkedListNode* newNode;
    struct  LinkedListNode* head = NULL;

    gets (inputArr);

    while (inputArr[0] != 0) // The user didn't press "Enter"
    {
        newNode=newLinkedListNode();
        newNode->tree=newHuffmanNode(inputArr[0],atoi(inputArr+2));

        head = addNode(&head, newNode);

        gets (inputArr);
    }

    head = buildHuffmanTree(&head);
    return head;
}
```

It seems OK, the user hits the 'Enter', the code go out from the while, but after the return, I get the error message:

> Stack around the variable 'inputArr' was corrupted

I guess I dont read the input from the keyboard properly.
I will be happy for some guidness.

Thanks.

Comment: If the input is more than three characters, you will overrun your `inputArr` variable. The Enter key will be one or two of those characters, depending on your system.

Comment: "*... more then **two** characters ...*" Mind the`NUL`-termination. @mah

Comment: `gets()` is impossible to use safely.  **Never** use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error is a perfect illustration to the reason why `gets` has been deprecated: it is prone to *buffer overruns*, which corrupt stack or whatever memory happens to be near the end of your buffer. When the user enters more than two characters, the first three get placed into the buffer, and the rest go into whatever happens to be in the memory after it, causing undefined behavior.

You need to replace the call of `gets` with a call of `fgets`, which accepts the size of the buffer, end prevents user input from overrunning it:

```
fgets (inputArr, 3, stdin);
```

> on every `while` iteration, the user hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and at the end, when he wants to stop, he hits only <kbd>enter</kbd>.

`fgets` considers `'\n'` part of the string, so when the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> the only character in the returned string will be `'\n'`:

```
while (inputArr[0] != '\n') { // The user didn't press "Enter"
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain the problem will. on every while iterration, the user hit the enter. and at the end, when he wants to stop, he hits only enter. for example: a enter, b enter, c enter, enter. at the last "enter" I need to go out from the while loop..

Comment: `fgets` should still work in this case.  It looks like you might need to perform some sort of input flush if the user enters too many characters, however.  This could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3876176/1089273.